# I am creating a sudoku game in C++ and i need to diplay the game board. How can i display an Array with charcters sectioned off?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, display

I was tasked to create a Sudoku game in my programming class using arrays.

I made a *very messy* attempt at trying to display the 9x9 Array with the "-" in-between the 3x3 squares.

The code compiles but the display of the board is off, the "-" is in places it shouldn't and isn't there sometimes when it should be.

I'm fairly new to C++ and thanks for the help! Here is what I have for the display functions:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
{
    if(board[x][y] == 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << "   ";
    }
    else
    {
     if (x > 3 && x < 7 && y > 3 && y < 7 && board[x-1][y-1] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x-1)][(y-1)] << " ";
    }
    else if (x > 3 && x < 7 && y < 3  && board[x-1][y] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x-1)][(y)] << " ";
    }
    else if (x > 7 && y < 3 && board[x-2][y] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x-2)][(y)] << " ";
    }
    else if (x < 3 && y > 3 && y < 7 && board[x][y-1] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x)][(y-1)] << " ";
    }
    else if (x < 3 && y > 7 && board[x][y-2] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x)][(y-2)] << " ";
    }
        else if (x > 3 && x < 7 && y > 7 && board[x-1][y-2] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x-1)][(y-2)] << " ";
    }
    else if (x > 7 && y > 7 && board[x-2][y-2] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x-2)][(y-2)] << " ";
    }
    else if (x > 7 && y > 3 && y < 7 && board[x-2][y-1] != 0)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[(x-2)][(y-1)] << " ";
    }

    else if (x < 3 && y < 3)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << board[x][y] << " ";
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << setw(2) << "-" << " ";
    }
    }
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: The best method to find out why a program is not working is to use a **debugger**.

Comment: you said your program was a 9x9 array, so why do your for loops go from 0 to 11?

Comment: You need to separate the _view_ of your data from the _model_ of it. The board should be stored as integers, that is what sudoku numbers are. A 9x9 grid, specifically. Then, you should write a function to transform this grid into the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the complexity:

```
static const char row_separator[] =
    "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n";
for (unsigned int board_row = 0; board_row < 9; ++board_row)
{
    std::cout << row_separator;
    cout << "| ";
    for (unsigned int board_column = 0;
         board_column < 9;
         ++board_column)
    {
       std::cout << board[board_row][board_column] << " |";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
std::cout << row_separator;
```

Many sudoko boards are declared as:

```
unsigned int board[9][9];
```

Because it is a 2 dimensional array, all the slots can be printed using 2 `for` loops.

Making the board a character array with spaces and other characters complicates the program.  Leave the spacing for the *printing* function.

Comment: should `std::cout << board[board_row][board_column] << " |";` be `std::cout << board[board_row][board_column] << " | ";` with a space after the | to make the alignment correct?